# Order ResultList of @ManyToMany connection

Tags: java, rest, jpa

I have a @ManyToMany Connection with a temporary table.
Table1 has 0..* Table2 and Table2 0..* Table1.
When i ask for the Elements of Table1 and Serialize it. I get a Array of Table1 containing an Array of Table2. The Array of Table1 is sorted by the Primary Key. But the Array Table2 in Table 1 is randomly sorted.

How can i sort the Array of Table2 in Table1 by its Primary Key?

**CODE:**

*Table1*

```
@Table(name = "Person")
@Entity
public class PersonDetail1 extends Person implements Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @JoinTable(name = "PERSON_ITEM", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "PERS_FK", referencedColumnName = "PERS_PK")}, inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "ITEM_FK", referencedColumnName = "ITEM_PK")})
  private Set<Item> items;
}
```

*Table2*

```
@Entity
public class Item implements Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  @Id
  @Column(name = "ITEM_PK")
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private int id;

  @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinTable(name = "PERSON_ITEM", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "ITEM_FK", referencedColumnName = "ITEM_PK")}, inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "PERS_FK", referencedColumnName = "PERS_PK")})
  private Set<PersonDetail1> personen;
}
```

*get Table1*

```
@Override
public List<PersonDetail1> getPersonen() throws DetailException {

  TypedQuery<PersonDetail1> q = em.createQuery("SELECT x from PersonDetail1 x", PersonDetail1.class);
  return q.getResultList();

}
```

*get Serialized Object*

```
@GET
@Path("/personen")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Override
public Response getPersonen(){

    return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).entity(persService.getPersonen()).build();

}
```

Comment: have you tried using ORDER BY?

Comment: Yes, but i couldn't figure it quit out.

Comment: I have no Problem to Order My Query "Normal". Like: "SELECT x from PersonDetail1 x ORDER BY x.id asc... But how to Order a List inside a List?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your requirement correctly, you want to have the `Collection` of `Items` in the `PersonDetail1` sorted.

You can either use the `OrderBy` annotation for that, or the `OrderColumn` annotation.

`OrderBy` can be used for dynamic ordering, meaning the sorting would occur on the query results.

`OrderColumn` can be used for persistent ordering - the order of the items would be stored in a column of the `Item` table. Persistent ordering has some quirks, so for most needs I would go with `OrderBy`:

I have some doubts that ordering would have any effects on the contents of a regular `Set`. You might want to use a sorted `Collection` implementation like `SortedSet`.

```
@OrderBy("id ASC")
private Set<Item> items;
```

The default ordering is `ASC`, so you would not need to write it explicitly, I did it for illustration purposes.